# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS- How to set the default-jre with a specific version?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I would like to install on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS an application that requires java 8.
When I want to install this application, an error is raised about the default-jre:

> Package default-jre is not configured yet

However, when I tried `java - version`, the java version returned is `openjdk version 1.8.0_191`

Please note, I don't want the version 10 or 11 of java.

So, do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: This question needs to migrate askubuntu.com? Please check/post in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: OK. I will post on askubuntu.com.

Comment: Answer is given on : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126929/ubuntu-18-04-lts-how-to-set-the-default-jre-with-a-specific-version